# Cloud SQL rejects connections above N simultaneously

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

This is error not about wrong connection url, this error is about quantity of (mysql) connection pool.
Are there any controls/settings to change the quantity of available connections to the MySQL in the Cloud? Approximately, MySQL can [accept 12 connections](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-sql-discuss/pending$20connections/google-cloud-sql-discuss/dncIO8owOUg/eLJ7HOyLFgAJ) simultaneously (I confirm that), above it generates such error. Okay. I reduced this count to 5 per one iteration. And it occurs again, but this time it 1 per 15 iterations.

list with successful queries and error
[image: good queries with error]

and it description:
[image: error description]

Does not matter I use [connection pool](https://github.com/kennberg/appengine-java-connection-pool) or create a new connection per query.

Comment: The 12 connections limit only applies to Google App Engine and it's on per app engine instance basis. It cannot be changed. Without seeing your code, it's hard to know what the problem is and what you mean by "5 per one iteration". Can you post your code (hopefully a simplified version of it)? Can you reduce it to a minimal code snippet? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Herman Yes I know about 12 connections. In my code I simply do:
`                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);`

I found later that I need to close statement and connection explicitly.

Comment: @Herman
Other story with the Connection pool (link above). As described I don't need to close connection and just leave it. 
when I try to set

`dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
dataSource.setUrl(url);                       
dataSource.setInitialSize(1);
dataSource.setMinIdle(1);
dataSource.setMaxActive(0);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(6);
dataSource.setMaxWait(-1); `

Pool halts after several minutes after start. And that behaviour is repatable each time I run app.